# My python 'if' statement is causing a syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Sorry, I know these are common but I couldn't find any answers on any quick articles.

My code starts a while True loop, followed by an input and then an if statement, an elif and then an else. The if and elif statements both break out of the loop once completed, and the else makes you input again until you fulfill one of the other two.

```
sleep(1)
print("Did lunch start before or after 12:00pm?")
while True:
    lunch_time = input()
    if lunch_time == "before" or if lunch_time == "Before":
        avgrams*=0.98
        STDEV*=0.98
        break
    elif lunch_time == "after" or if lunch_time == "After":
        break
    else:
        sleep(1)
        print("Sorry, I don't understand.")
        sleep(1)
        print("Please only answer with 'before' or 'after' (with no punctuation).")
```

I started my code, when I got to this part (the first line here is line 84) I was expecting to answer something random to make sure the else statement worked, then answer one of the other two to break out of the loop and continue. However upon running my code this if statement causes a syntax error, with invalid syntax.

```
  File "main.py", line 88
    if lunch_time == "before" or if lunch_time == "Before":
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: remove the second if: `if lunch_time == "before" or lunch_time == "Before":` you can also rewrite it in a more concise way: `if lunch_time in ["before", "Before"]:`

Comment: If you use Python 3.11 or later, the syntax error should indicate the second `if` specifically as the source of the error.

Answer (score 2):

When using your logical operators within an `if` block, you do not need to declare `if` again after you type the logical operator (`and`, `or`, `not`). Your program is failing because you are including the `if` statement once more within your if statement.

Another problem that is that you have *another* if-statement within your `elif` statement. The order, if including an `elif`, should always be `if->elif->else`. Please let me know if you have any further questions!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can think if-elif-else in python like this.

```
if <condition> or/and <condition> . . .:
    # code
elif <condition> or/and <condition> . . .:
    # code
else:
    #code
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).